# A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value ‘undefined’

Tags: jquery, service-worker

If the user attempts to open an uncached page while offline my service worker should run the below method `unableToResolve()` but instead the page displays:

> Unable to connect Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server

In the console I get the error:

> Failed to load ‘www.examplesite.co.uk’. A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value ‘undefined’.

My service worker runs fine otherwise so I'm not sure what this could be.

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  var request = event.request;
  if (request.method !== 'GET') {
    return;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(cached) {
      var networked = fetch(event.request).then(fetchedFromNetwork, function() {
        return cached;
      }).catch(unableToResolve);
      return networked;

      function fetchedFromNetwork(response) {

        var cacheCopy = response.clone();
        caches.open(version + 'offlinemode').then(function add(cache) {
          cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy);
        });
        return response;
      }

      function unableToResolve() {
        return new Response('<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>', {
          status: 503,
          statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
          headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
          })
        });
      }
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my friend we figured out the issue. We needed to throw an error before it would go into unableToResolve() :')

```
event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(cached) {
        var networked = fetch(event.request).then(fetchedFromNetwork, function(){if(cached === undefined){throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');}return cached;}).catch(unableToResolve);
        return networked;

        function fetchedFromNetwork(response) {
          var cacheCopy = response.clone();
          caches.open(version + 'offlinemode').then(function add(cache) {
              cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy);
          });
          return response;
        }
        function unableToResolve () {
          return new Response('<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>', {
            status: 503,
            statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
            headers: new Headers({
              'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            })
          });
        }
      })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:  The problem was CORS only active on some routes, not global on the server.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286683/7486794