# Firefox "A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value ‘undefined’" for Local Server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, firefox, service-worker

When running a local server from Visual Studio, Firefox will error out and not load the page correctly. It shows this error:

```
Failed to load ‘https://localhost/js/mqtt.js’. A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that resolved with non-Response value ‘undefined’. serviceworker.js:19:10
```

it works fine on Chrome. It also works fine on Firefox when the server is on a cloud-based Azure server. Here is the code for the service worker:

```
// Service worker file for PWA
var CACHE_NAME = 'v5';
var urlsToCache = [
    '/index.html'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    // Perform install steps
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function (cache) {
                console.log('Opened cache');
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).then(response => {
            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
            return response;
        }).catch(_ => {
            return caches.match(event.request);
        })
    )
});
```

I am unsure what this error is caused by. One workaround is to go to "about:debugging#workers" and unregister the serviceworkers manually. Then refreshing the page will allow it to load correctly. However I need a solution, not a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that code, I'd expect to see that error message if the following two conditions are true:

- `fetch(event.request)` rejects.
- `caches.match(event.request)` results in a cache miss, which causes the promise to resolve with `undefined`.

This isn't really out of the ordinary—it's just the logic you've written in your service worker, and the behavior depends on both the current network/server conditions, as well as the state of your local cache.

Comment: That makes sense, but does that mean it is also browser specific? Because it works fine on Chrome, and it doesn't on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The same mistake happened to me. The problem was that I had CORS disabled for some route on the server.

Enabling CORS on the server for all routes solved it.

```
// Enable cors for all routes
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
// To enable cors only for a single route must be added on the app.get
// app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), nextCallback() )
```